# Matlab - Latex interpreter in array of strings

Tags: arrays, string, matlab, latex, interpreter

I need to make subplots with different values in the title strings, for that I use num2str and compose a new string.

So this is the function I use currently, however, I want Matlab to use the latex interpreter

```
title(['x_{c}(t) = cos(2\pi' num2str(f(j)) ')}'])
```

When I try to use

```
title(['x_{c}(t) = cos(2\pi' num2str(f(j)) ')}'], 'Interpreter', 'Latex')
```

It doesn't work either.

How do I use the interpreter in that manner ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, its not the interpreter wrong, its just your Latex is wrong.

You have an extra `}`, there is no space between the `\pi` and the number and you are not using equation notation `$ $`

```
title(['$x_{c}(t) = cos(2\pi ' num2str(f(j)) ')$'], 'Interpreter', 'Latex')
```

Comment: Ah ! You are right ... Actually my syntax worked for strings that were in only one part. For example

    ylabel('|e_{1}(t)|') or
['x_{c}(t) = cos(2\pi' num2str(f(j)) 't)']; for legend cells.

So I assumed it would work as well (I'm using matlab version 2016a). Thank you !